# discord.py trying to make command that passes 2 args to google api sheets

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, discord.py

I am hoping someone can assist me, I'm not a coder and struggling a bit to get my bot command working with google sheets api.

What I want to do:
I want to pass 2 args written by the user from the command.command into the api script, I found this on codegrepper:

```
@bot.command()
async def args(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    await bot.say('You sent {} and {}'.format(arg1, arg2))
```

Using the google sheets api quickstart script for python I did this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'secrets.json'

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# The ID spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '*************************************'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
#result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
#                                range="Player!B2:C2").execute()
#values = result.get('values', [])

test = [["MyNiks",'Gs2']]

request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range="Player!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS", body={"values":test})
response = request.execute()

#request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
#                                range="Player!B3:C3", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":test})
#response = request.execute()

print()
```

I want to turn the above into a bot command but replace 'test; with the args1 and args2, I dont know how to get the args into the script!

This is what I have tried:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

class seasonenter(commands.Cog):

    def __init__ (self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def seasonenter(self, ctx, arg1, arg2):
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'secrets.json'

        creds = None
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
                SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

        # The ID spreadsheet.
        SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '**************************************'

        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Sheets API
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        #result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
        #                                range="Player!B2:C2").execute()
        #values = result.get('values', [])

        test = [["arg1",'arg2']]

        request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                        range="Player!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS", body={"values":test})
        response = request.execute()
        await ctx.send('You sent {} and {}'.format(arg1))

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(seasonenter(bot))
```

So when the discord user types: &seasonenter myname, teamname it should take the 2 args and pass them to the api and write it to the google sheet. Currently it writes to the spreadsheet but its writing literally args1 and args2 and not the arguments typed by the user.
[screenshot of the google sheets table with entered args](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDWjo.jpg)

I feel I'm so close but I just can't seem to figure out how its done, hoping someone can help set me on the right path.

Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: you need `test = [[ arg1, arg2 ]]` without `" "` `' '`. And you can simply use `print(test)` to see what you have in this variable.

Comment: Hey Furas,

Thank you so much, it works perfectly now. Appreciate it! So happy :)
Have a great weekend further! All the best!